# hover lightoff (turned off) when mouse leaves the div (almost done but miss something that cant find)

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, mouseover, light

I'am using a joomla menu and i've tryed to put 1 effect when the mouse it's hover the menu ("lights" go off position.... 
But **the problem it's removing** (get out) that **hover**  position **when mouse**  goes away from the div id="menu" to any other div / position in the website...

Here's the full code that we can test it (and update): http://jsfiddle.net/FEBkJ/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="standout">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" />
</div>
<div id="the_lights" style="display: block; opacity: 0; "></div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu{height:30px;width:960px;zoom:1;margin-top:5px;background:#C15F56;z-index:1001;}
#the_lights {opacity:0.5; background-color:#000; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:10; top:0; left:0; position:fixed; }
.standout {position: relative;z-index: 10000}​
```

Script:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#the_lights").fadeTo(1, 0);
        jQuery(".turnon").hide();

        jQuery("#menu").hover(function () {
            jQuery("#the_lights").css({ 'display': 'block' });
            jQuery("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
            jQuery(".turnon").show();
            jQuery(".turnoff").hide();
        });          
    });​
```

I've also searched here in the forum for some solution... but cant find it ...
Thanks for any help!
Best Regards from Pt!

Comment: What is `#pesqui`? I don't see that in your markup...

Comment: sorry.. #pesqui it's one div that i did to test the efect turn off at bottom of the div #menu i forgot to wrote here that... but it's not needed, i just wanna remove the effect when mouse goes out from the div id #menu area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and looking at the Fiddle, you want to the `div` `#the_lights` to fade back to 0 opacity when you mouse leaves `#menu` correct?

If so, you can use `.mouseenter` and `'.mouseleave'

```
jQuery("#menu").mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery("#the_lights").css({ 'display': 'block' });
    jQuery("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
    jQuery(".turnon").show();
    jQuery(".turnoff").hide();
});

jQuery("#menu").mouseleave(function () {
    jQuery("#the_lights").css({ 'display': 'block' });
    jQuery("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow", 0);
    jQuery(".turnon").show();
    jQuery(".turnoff").hide();
});
```

Or you can use the `.toggle` to combine the function into one.

I couldn't find any reference to the `.turnon` and `.turnoff` classes, so I assume they've on another part of the page.

Comment: Hi. Thanks! works :) i've adapted the code from an demo page here: http://net4.ccs.neu.edu/home/adityak/experiments/jquery/LightsOff.aspx 
I dont understand why they use the classes ".turnon" or ".turnoff" i dont have this styles in  CSS.... like that demo site dont have that classes too!

Comment: but i also have this msg in firebug when i move the mouse hover the sub menu links: "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future."

Comment: @Lipes You can no doubt remove the `.turnon` and `.turnoff` classes if there's no reference to them (in the page you referenced it's used to swap the buttons over). Also, make sure you're using the latest version of jQuery as this will have the latest functions and should be fully compatable.